# How to store current page number into \def?

Tags: page-numbering

This is what I'm doing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\start{\thepage}
some long text for 4-5 pages

Here: \start -- \thepage
\end{document}
```

I'm getting: `Here 4 -- 4`. I'm expecting `Here 1 -- 4`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `\label{start}` and then `\pageref{start}`. This will need two compilations, but isn't affected by the asychronous page breaking.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried this, but `\pageref{start}` prints `1\hbox{}` instead of just `1`

Comment: As the answer shows, you have to make sure \thepage is expanded at the moment you define \start, so \start is a macro for the page number at the time, rather than a macro for another macro whose meaning will be redefined later.

Comment: @yegor256: Where do you get that `\pageref{start}` includes an `\hbox{}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate (and reliable) way of getting the page numbers is to set a `\label` and extract the page number via `\ref` elsewhere in the document. [`refcount`](//ctan.org/pkg/refcount) allows you to extract the page number via `\getpagerefnumber` (if you wish to perform calculations, say), or you can do this using `\ref` as mentioned before:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\label{start}%
\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum

\label{finish}%
Here: \getpagerefnumber{start} -- \getpagerefnumber{finish}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ulrike's solution is the most efficient, but to answer your question, here's a solution using `\edef`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

 \lipsum\lipsum

 \edef\start{\thepage} % mark page 3
 
  Here: \start{} -- \thepage
 
 \lipsum\lipsum
 
  Here: \start{} -- \thepage

\end{document}
```

A solution defining a new counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{start}
\begin{document}

\lipsum\lipsum

\setcounter{start}{\value{page}}

Here: \thestart{} -- \thepage

\lipsum\lipsum

Here: \thestart{} -- \thepage

\end{document}
```

Comment: you should probably note that while this works for the example in the question, `\def\thestart{1}` would also work, you can't do this anywhere other than after a forced page break such as `\clearpage` as `value{page}` and `\thepage` do not have useful value in the body of the document.

Comment: I do not understand. I used \edef...The examples I have just edited also work for the other pages

Comment: @Ivan: Try [this example](https://pastebin.com/raw/SuTxpTkp). Visually you'd think that the `\edef` should happen immediately after `\lipsum*\lipsum*` has been typeset. However, at the time of reaching `\edef`, nothing has been set. Instead, TeX is still constructing the pages. As such, the `\edef` results in `\start` being 1. Weird, right? But that's what David is trying to say.

Comment: @Ivan yes you used `\edef` but it only worked as you were at the start of the document (where you know already the value is 1) you can not do this at a general position within the document, only after a forced page break.

Comment: @werner Ok. Now I understand. But if I add a blank line after \lipsum* it works as expected.

Comment: @David Carlisle... so it seems to me that a paragraph break is enough.

Comment: @Ivan: The blank line would force a paragraph and therefore initiate the setting of the paragraph on TeX's side. Since the accumulation of text up to that point is a couple of pages' worth, the pages themselves are shipped out (and, consequently, the page numbers are increased). That's why you see a correct page number. However, in general, your use of `\edef` might not happen with a proper paragraph break between them, or it could be at the start of a paragraph when TeX is still assembling content, which, could spill over to a subsequent page. So, your solution is not always reliable.

Comment: @Ivan no the page number will be wrong in general. that is why `\pageref` exists and why it takes (at least) two passes of latex for it to stabilise. There are many reasons why it will be wrong not least that floats may be inserted so the paragraph ends on a later page than the current value of `\thepage`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks to both of you for the explanation